# Does anyone know a simple way to conditionally route to a page in next, react js, or js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a form and I want the onSubmit function to contain a switch or an if that routes to different pages depending on form submit.

For example consider the following onSubmit function body: (but where goTo is an executable JS function that routes to /account, /blog, etc.)

```
'''
if (formData == 1) {
  goTo('/account');
}
else if (formData == 2) {
  goTo('/blog');
}
else if (formData == 3) {
  goTo('/about');
}
else {
  goTo('/');
}
'''
```

I am using next react next link and react-router. If you know of any libraries that would be useful for this please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically navigate using React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read any documentation about doing this in React, Next, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `react-router`, you will want to use something from the appropriate from the library.

It appears this question provides plenty of solutions: [Programmatically navigate using React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js you can create paths using your filesystem and `[foo].js` filenames.

For instance, you could create the file /[part1]/[part2].js`, and it would match any URL in the form` /anything/anything`.

See the following for further info: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

See also: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes (particularly the section at bottom about "Catch all routes").